# Windws Server 2003 LDAPS Returning Expired Server Certificate

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, ldap, openldap

I'm having issues finding the location of en expired certificate that one of my LDAP servers responds with during an LDAPS bind attempt.

I'm using Linux's ldapsearch to perform specific tasks during user creation but recently discovered the certificate expired. I have renewed said certificate and placed it in the personal store on that ldapserver but after debugging the SSL connection it still responds with the previously expired certificate.

Can anyone tell me where this certificate would be stored on Windows Server 2003. I've found multiple post regarding the store in 2008 but that does not exist in 2003. I've searched the whole store using certutil trying to match the serial on this certificate but can't find it anywhere.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: You know 2k3 is EOL, right?

Comment: @EEAA Why is that relevant? They have a Win2k3 server and want to know where the cert store is for the LDAP certificate. A lot of companies run server that are EOL doesn't mean we can't help. Admittedly WU and keeping the server security patched would be an issue but is this anything to do with the actual question?

Comment: @Lankymart It is relevant because it is a horrible practice to continue using products that are unsupported and insecure. While this cert problem is not ideal, it's the least of the OPs problems.

Comment: @EEAA Actually think I've [answer my own question](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/8410/199051).

Comment: @Lankymart You'll notice I did not close this question. Now, if you would like to contribute in a productive manner, you may consider that it's a waste of time to confront me for giving the OP a heads up about a very risky situation, even if it's ancillary to the question itself.

Comment: @EEAA sorry not my intention. I was just trying to understand why you called him out on it, now I do.

Comment: @EEAA I'm aware that 2k3 is EOL but this ad-hoc network provides a specific service until it's decommissioned (very soon).

Comment: @SteveeeePerry Fair enough. We just like to ensure people are aware of things like this.

Comment: Be sure you've put the new cert in the Personal store of the Computer account and not your User account. You may also need to reboot the DC (which will restart Kerberos service) for it to recognize the new cert.

Comment: @Craig620 You're right - I ended up rebooting the server as a last-ditch effort. It's now responding with the new certificate that I placed in the Personal store.

Comment: @SteveeeePerry If it worked, you can add an answer and mark it accepted, thus the question will be of use to other in situation like yours!

Comment: @yagmoth555 Not seeing anything on this page that allows me to mark Craig620's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you've put the new cert in the Personal store of the Computer account and not your User account. You may also need to reboot the DC (which will restart Kerberos service) for it to recognize the new cert.

Comment: How does accepting an answer work http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work